# Regular Expression to filter MAC ADDRESS

Tags: javascript, python, regex

I am struck in writing regular expression for below format
XXXXXXG0-XXXX-XXXX-1923-785FEABCD128
Above format is to filter MAC Address, so i need those MAC ADDRESS which has the characters defined in the above format and length

Is it possible to write regexp for above format?  X characters can be
alphanumeric. But other non X characters should be same.

```
ABCDEFG0-GHYD-SDER-1923-785FEABCD128 - Valid

ABCDEFH0-GHYD-SDER-0923-995FEABCD120 - Invalid

ABCDEFG0-GHYD-SDER-0923-995FEABCD120 - Invalid
```

Comment: Why a regex? Why not `if address.endswith('1923-785FEABCD128')`?

Comment: @C.Nivs, there's a `G0` in there, too. But your point is a good one: string matching is likely a better fit than regex here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}G0-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-1923-785FEABCD128$
```

Explanation:

`^` matches beginning of the string

`[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}` matches any alphanumeric character 6 times

`G0-` matches that text exactly

`[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-` any alphanumeric character 4 times followed by a hyphen (appears twice)

`1923-785FEABCD128` matches that text exactly

`$` matches the end of the string

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

patt = re.compile('[A-Z0-9]{6}G0-[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{4}-1923-785FEABCD128')

for test in ['ABCDEFG0-GHYD-SDER-1923-785FEABCD128', 'ABCDEFH0-GHYD-SDER-0923-995FEABCD120', 'ABCDEFG0-GHYD-SDER-0923-995FEABCD120']:
    if patt.match(test):
        print(f'{test} - Valid')
    else:
        print(f'{test} - Invalid')
```

prints

```
ABCDEFG0-GHYD-SDER-1923-785FEABCD128 - Valid
ABCDEFH0-GHYD-SDER-0923-995FEABCD120 - Invalid
ABCDEFG0-GHYD-SDER-0923-995FEABCD120 - Invalid
```

Comment: heh pretty much the same answer as @devjoco, except that one allows lowercase letters

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of string-matching instead of a regex, you could use this solution:

```py
mac_addresses = [
    'ABCDEFG0-GHYD-SDER-1923-785FEABCD128',
    'ABCDEFH0-GHYD-SDER-0923-995FEABCD120',
    'ABCDEFG0-GHYD-SDER-0923-995FEABCD120'
]

for address in mac_addresses:
    # splits 3 times, leaving the last two groups together
    # for easier string matching
    first, *_, last = address.split('-', 3)
   
    if first.endswith('G0') and last == '1923-785FEABCD128':
        match = 'Valid'
    else:
        match = 'Invalid'

    print(f"{address} - {match}")
```

Which prints

```
ABCDEFG0-GHYD-SDER-1923-785FEABCD128 - Valid
ABCDEFH0-GHYD-SDER-0923-995FEABCD120 - Invalid
ABCDEFG0-GHYD-SDER-0923-995FEABCD120 - Invalid
```

The benefit here? If you need to change conditions or add a new condition, you don't need to modify/keep up with a regex